# Pass data from onRowDataBound to onRowUpdating in ASP Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView on aspx that accepts OnRowDataBound and OnRowUpdating. The AutoGenerateColumns is set to true. My task is to update the textbox to dropdown.

On RowDataBound, I created a sample code snippet to change the text box to dropdown list:

```
     protected void gv_OnRowDataBound(obejct sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
          if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
          {
            DropDownList ddlEdit = new DropdownList();
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test1", "Test1"));
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test2", "Test2"));
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddlEdit);

            TextBox tbox = e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as Textbox;
            if (tbox != null)
            {
               tBox.Visible = false;
            }
          }
     }
```

How do I pass the data of DropDownList from OnRowDataBound to OnRowUpdating on DataRow? Below is my current code from OnRowUpdating:

```
     GridViewRow gvr = gvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     DataRow drNew = dt.NewRow();

     for(int i = 0l; i < Gvr.Cells.Count, i++) 
     {
        drNew[i] = ((TextBox)gvr.Cells[i].Controls[0]).Text.Trim(); //Result is always the same like before for Cell[5], even though I slect the dropdown to "Test2" value.
     }
```

I also tried to get the type of the type, it still returns a TextBox

```
     gvr.Cells[i].Controls[0].GetType(); // When i = 5, which is I indicated on the first code snippet is DropDownList, returns TextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddlEdit);
```

Here, you added your ddl to Controls collection and it will be the 2nd control in that list.

```
gvr.Cells[i].Controls[1].GetType();
```

should give you ddl that you want.